# How to find margin of error for 99% confidence interval for skewed distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, standard-error, skewness, histogram

[Google Sheet of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i7glInLkGLUfl19pbSTIlg7RX837vkpbhCJbSez5dX0/edit?usp=sharing)

I have the value and the frequency of the data. As you can see in the data sheet, the count number is quite high, so I am not able to write out the entire list of the data (ex. 2, 6, 23, 34, 35, 36, 36, 36 etc.)

I found the median is 77 and I want to know from the median, how much does 99% of the data cover? In other words, the range of data that contains the 99% of the majority starting from the middle.

I mean starting from the median which have 50% on each side of the distribution. Then starting at the median, take 49.5% on the left and 49.5% on the right. Then I can see what the two Values are and get the range of data with 99%.

Comment: The median does not answer your question.  Also, if you "start from the middle," how can you hope to cover more than 50% of the data??  Could you explain the process you have in mind?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for taking an interest in my question. I meant starting from the median which have 50% on each side  of the distribution. Then starting at the median, take 49.5% on the left and 49.5% on the right. Then I can see what the two Values are and get the range of data with 99%.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean in the title by the "margin of error for the 95% confidence interval." That also doesn't seem to represent what you say you want in the question: "the range of data that contains the 99% of the majority starting from the middle." That latter statement would just seem to require finding the 0.5th and 99.5th percentiles of the present data themselves, to find the limits within which 99% of the current data reside. Please clarify the situation by editing the question (and the title, if necessary), as comments can be easily overlooked and can get lost.